# Why this occur about hidden files

Tags: windows, cygwin

I've found 2 hidden files on my drive D:/ , I found them by accident, because one day I opened a picture (1 picture exactly on my drive D:/), and by accident I push right navigation button on keyboard, and there is another picture WHICH familiar with me, and there is another, okay maybe this is not important but this is the name (1. AlbumArtSmall.jpg, 2. Folder.jpg), okay I think these 2 jpg files is hidden, but when I unhidden by the step : Tools > Folder Options > View > Show hidden files and folders, but It doesn't make sense (there is no such file on D:/), after that I check it again by command prompt, which is the step :

```
1. %drive% d:
2. D:> dir
3. there is no such file (those 2 jpg file)
```

But, when I check with cygwin terminal as I know this is for Linux OS (my OS is windows7 by the way :

```
1. /cygdrive/d
2. $ dir
3. there is such file (those 2 jpg file)
```

I know this is not a big problem, but I'm curious why this is happened? And if I want to delete these 2 files, I can do nothing, maybe there is a way to delete them by cygwin terminal command, but the problem for me not because I want to delete them, but more for why this is occur?
Thanks in advance, sorry for my English.

Comment: If you set Explorer to show system files and hidden files both then you will also see these two files in explorer. PS: These seem to be Windows Media Player files, for album/folder art.

Comment: I've done that, but they doesn't show up in the explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably `hidden` and `system`. You can display them in explorer by selecting, in addition to "show hidden files", the "show system files" option.
On the command line, `dir /a` will show you hidden and system files, too. To delete them from the command line, type `attrib -h -s -r *.jpg` to remove hidden, system, and readonly attributes from all jpg files (for example). Then just normal `del file.jpg`.

Comment: I've tried del AlbumArtSmall.jpg, It gives warning : Could not find D:\AlbumArtSmall.jpg

Comment: did you do the attrib first, as i suggested?

Comment: I've tried that attrib command by the way, but It is not recognize as command

Comment: this command exists since ms-dos 3 http://www.computerhope.com/attribhl.htm, i'm sure you have it.

Comment: Just to ensure, this is what I write :
D:\>attrib -h -s -r AlbumArtSmall.jpg (Enter)
'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command ....
Does my text wrong?

Comment: maybe you have ruined your search path (or your windows installation). Try `C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe`. btw, if you type it without parameters, it'll list all files with their attributes.

Comment: Thousand thanks man, I've add my system path to system32, and use the attrib.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin does not recognize windows-like hidden files (thus showing you them), because in Linux hidden files are marked with a leading point. If you use a windows shell on "unix-"hidden files, you will see them, too, but cygwin should not.
For deletion: Afaik you can make them visible and then simply delete them.

Comment: okay I guess I'm wrong about how cygwin works, but it detects those 2 files (so we can say those 2 files is not hidden), but in fact I dont find such file, I've unhidden by the Folder Options>View>Show hidden file and folder, but nothing happened (those 2 file is not shown up). I'm confusing now.

Comment: @Hikikomori: Look at the answer of ths, there this is explained

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt won't show hidden files if you execute `dir`. If you want to see these hidden files, then use `dir /a`.

Comment: yes, I've tried it, now it detect those 2 file.